# Length function in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I am self learning measure theory, and my question is:

Is the length function in measure theory applied to the intervals $(a,b) , [a,b] , (a,b] , [a,b)$ equal to $|b-a|$? And if so, why is it true?

Comment: Where are you learning measure theory from?

Comment: NPTEL online lectures

Comment: I meant which book, if any?

Comment: I am not referring any book at the moment

Comment: What is what you call "length function"? $|b-a|$ is the Lebesgue measure of these sets. There exists other measures.

Answer (score 1):

In some ways, measure theory on the real line really starts with the question: suppose that I take the "size" of an interval to be its length (as you say); can I generalize this to find the sizes of other things too, in a way that is internally consistent?

So the fact that the length of an interval is defined in this way isn't so much an implication... it is a definition.  It is 'true' because we find it to be a desirable property for something that we call a measure of sets on the real line.

Of course, that internal consistency bit is the key, and is why we define things like the the Borel and Lebesgue sigma algebras, etc.